# Dialog box improperly repaints its background

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I have a dialog box that should have a custom image as a background.

I do not have the whole image as a bitmap or any other format, so I have to draw it from scratch.

I use an `icon` (the male in the left bottom of the screenshot) , one `EMF` file (the map on the screen shot below), and the rest consists of a green gradient brush, light gray hatched brush, and text - all being drawn using `GDI`. The result of my drawing looks like this (the screen shot includes the controls too):

[image]

The problem I face manifests when I move the dialog box **to the left** and then move it back to its original position. The artifacts happening are illustrated at the bottom of the picture in the next screenshot:

[image]

The dialog box is the **modeless** one, and I draw the entire image in `WM_CTLCOLORDIALOG` returning `NULL_BRUSH` afterwards.

Here is the relevant code snippet for the `WM_CTLCOLORDIALOG` handler ( **note that I draw directly on the DC, there is no double buffering**. The reason for it is that this was a quick test code things went wrong quickly):

```
case WM_CTLCOLORDLG:
    {   
        RECT rect; // dialog's client rectangle

        GetClientRect( hwnd, &rect );

        // ligh gray brush for hatched brush

        HBRUSH hbPozadina = CreateSolidBrush( RGB( 242, 242, 242 ) );

        FillRect( (HDC)wParam, &rect, hbPozadina );

        // cleanup

        DeleteObject( hbPozadina );

        // draw grid "manualy"

        LOGBRUSH lbPozadina;

        HGDIOBJ hPenPozadina = NULL, hOldPenPozadina;

        lbPozadina.lbColor = RGB( 255, 255, 255 );
        lbPozadina.lbHatch = 0;
        lbPozadina.lbStyle = BS_SOLID;

        hPenPozadina = ExtCreatePen( PS_COSMETIC | PS_SOLID, 1, &lbPozadina, 0, NULL); 

        hOldPenPozadina = SelectObject((HDC)wParam, hPenPozadina);

        // draw vertical lines

        for( int i = rect.left + 12; i< rect.right; i += 12)
        {
            MoveToEx((HDC)wParam, i, rect.top, NULL );

            LineTo((HDC)wParam, i, rect.bottom - rect.top + 1 );
        }

        // draw horizontal lines

        for( int i = rect.top + 12; i< rect.bottom; i += 12)
        {
            MoveToEx((HDC)wParam, rect.left, i, NULL );

            LineTo((HDC)wParam, rect.right - rect.left + 1, i );
        }

        //clean up

        SelectObject((HDC)wParam, hOldPenPozadina);

        DeleteObject(hPenPozadina);

        // draw metafile of the map

        HENHMETAFILE hemf = GetEnhMetaFile( L".\\resources\\KartaDlg.emf" );
        ENHMETAHEADER emh; 
        GetEnhMetaFileHeader( hemf, sizeof(emh), &emh ); 

        // remove the "status bar" from the calculation

        RECT r;

        r.top = rect.top;
        r.bottom = rect.bottom - 30;
        r.left = rect.left;
        r.right = rect.right;

        // calculate rescaled metafile

        UINT o_height = emh.rclFrame.bottom - emh.rclFrame.top, 
            o_width =  emh.rclFrame.right - emh.rclFrame.left;

        float scale = 0.5;

        scale = (float)( r.right - r.left ) / o_width;

        if( (float)( r.bottom - r.top ) / o_height  <  scale )
            scale = (float)( r.bottom - r.top ) / o_height;

        int marginX = ( r.right - r.left ) - (int)( o_width * scale );
        int marginY = ( r.bottom - r.top ) - (int)( o_height * scale );

        marginX /= 2;
        marginY /= 2;

        r.left = r.left + marginX;
        r.right = r.right - marginX;
        r.top = r.top + marginY;
        r.bottom = r.bottom - marginY;

        // Draw the picture.  

        PlayEnhMetaFile( (HDC)wParam, hemf, &r ); 

        // Release the metafile handle.  

        DeleteEnhMetaFile(hemf); 

        // this function draws green gradient and icon

        drawFooter( (HDC)wParam, rect, 
            RGB( 0x48, 0xAC, 0xC6), RGB( 0x31, 0x83, 0x99 ) ); 

        //========= draw right text in status bar =============//

        SetBkMode( (HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT );

        SIZE sBaner; // needed for proper positioning

        HFONT hf, hfOld;

        long lfHeight;

        lfHeight = -MulDiv( 8, GetDeviceCaps( (HDC)wParam, LOGPIXELSY), 72 );

        hf = CreateFont( lfHeight, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, TRUE, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Arial Black" );

        hfOld = (HFONT)SelectObject( (HDC)wParam, hf ); // needed for proper cleanup

        GetTextExtentPoint32( (HDC)wParam, 
            L"ЦЕНТАР ЗА ОБНОВЉИВЕ ВОДНЕ ЕНЕРГЕТСКЕ РЕСУРСЕ",
            wcslen(L"ЦЕНТАР ЗА ОБНОВЉИВЕ ВОДНЕ ЕНЕРГЕТСКЕ РЕСУРСЕ"), 
            &sBaner );

        // position it properly

        r.bottom = rect.bottom;
        r.right = rect.left + sBaner.cx + 30;
        r.left = rect.left + 30;
        r.top = rect.bottom - rect.top - 30;

        // draw it 

        DrawTextEx( (HDC)wParam, 
            L"РУДАРСКО ГЕОЛОШКИ ФАКУЛТЕТ\nЦЕНТАР ЗА ОБНОВЉИВЕ ВОДНЕ ЕНЕРГЕТСКЕ РЕСУРСЕ",
            wcslen(L"РУДАРСКО ГЕОЛОШКИ ФАКУЛТЕТ\nЦЕНТАР ЗА ОБНОВЉИВЕ ВОДНЕ ЕНЕРГЕТСКЕ РЕСУРСЕ"), 
            &r, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_NOCLIP | DT_WORDBREAK, 0 );

        SelectObject( (HDC)wParam, hfOld ); // proper cleanup

        DeleteObject( hf );

        //============== right text in the status bar ==================//

        lfHeight = -MulDiv( 10, GetDeviceCaps( (HDC)wParam, LOGPIXELSY), 72 );

        hf = CreateFont( lfHeight, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, TRUE, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Arial" );

        hfOld = (HFONT)SelectObject( (HDC)wParam, hf ); // needed for proper cleanup

        GetTextExtentPoint32( (HDC)wParam, 
            L" Дејан Миленић & Ана Врањеш © 2013 сва права задржана",
            wcslen(L" Дејан Миленић & Ана Врањеш © 2013 сва права задржана"), 
            &sBaner );

        // position it properly

        r.bottom = rect.bottom;
        r.right = rect.right - 10;
        r.left = rect.right - rect.left - sBaner.cx - 10;
        r.top = rect.bottom - rect.top - sBaner.cy;

        // draw it 

        DrawTextEx( (HDC)wParam, 
            L" Дејан Миленић & Ана Врањеш © 2013 сва права задржана",
            wcslen(L" Дејан Миленић & Ана Врањеш © 2013 сва права задржана"), 
            &r, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_NOCLIP | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_NOPREFIX, 0 );

        // perform proper cleanup

        SelectObject( (HDC)wParam, hfOld );

        DeleteObject(hf);
    }
    return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
```

To make this even more complete, I submit the `drawFooter` function and its helper functions:

```
// Fills triangle with gradient brush

void GradientTriangle( HDC MemDC, 
    LONG x1, LONG y1, LONG x2, LONG y2, LONG x3, LONG y3, 
    COLORREF top, COLORREF bottom )
{
    TRIVERTEX vertex[3];

    vertex[0].x     = x1;
    vertex[0].y     = y1;
    vertex[0].Red   = GetRValue(bottom) << 8;
    vertex[0].Green = GetGValue(bottom) << 8;
    vertex[0].Blue  = GetBValue(bottom) << 8;
    vertex[0].Alpha = 0x0000;

    vertex[1].x     = x2;
    vertex[1].y     = y2;
    vertex[1].Red   = GetRValue(top) << 8;
    vertex[1].Green = GetGValue(top) << 8;
    vertex[1].Blue  = GetBValue(top) << 8;
    vertex[1].Alpha = 0x0000;

    vertex[2].x     = x3;
    vertex[2].y     = y3; 
    vertex[2].Red   = GetRValue(bottom) << 8;
    vertex[2].Green = GetGValue(bottom) << 8;
    vertex[2].Blue  = GetBValue(bottom) << 8;
    vertex[2].Alpha = 0x0000;

    // Create a GRADIENT_TRIANGLE structure that
    // references the TRIVERTEX vertices.

    GRADIENT_TRIANGLE gTriangle;

    gTriangle.Vertex1 = 0;
    gTriangle.Vertex2 = 1;
    gTriangle.Vertex3 = 2;

    // Draw a shaded triangle.

    GradientFill( MemDC, vertex, 3, &gTriangle, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_TRIANGLE);
}

// draw the window's footer ( "status bar" )

void drawFooter( HDC MemDC, RECT r, COLORREF top, COLORREF bottom )
{
    // bottom triangle

    GradientTriangle( MemDC, 
        r.right, r.bottom, 
        ( r.right - r.left ) / 2,
        r.bottom - r.top - 15,
        r.left, 
        r.bottom, 
        top, bottom );

    // upper triangle

    GradientTriangle( MemDC, 
        r.right, r.bottom - r.top - 30, 
        ( r.right - r.left ) / 2, 
        r.bottom - r.top - 15,
        r.left, 
        r.bottom - r.top - 30, 
        top, bottom );

    // left triangle

    GradientTriangle( MemDC, 
        r.left, r.bottom, 
        ( r.right - r.left ) / 2, 
        r.bottom - r.top - 15,
        r.left, 
        r.bottom - r.top - 30, 
        top, bottom );

    // right triangle

    GradientTriangle( MemDC, 
        r.right, 
        r.bottom - r.top - 30,
        ( r.right - r.left ) / 2,
        r.bottom - r.top - 15, 
        r.right, 
        r.bottom, 
        top, bottom );

    // draw icon

    DrawIconEx( MemDC, r.left, r.bottom - r.top - 30, 
        hiAdmin, // a global variable for icon
        30, 30, NULL, NULL, DI_NORMAL );
}
```

**Visual Styles are enabled** - this might matter, I do not know.

I did not handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` nor `WM_SIZE` or `WM_MOVE` ( **dialog box can not be resized.** ). I have tried but it did not help ( returning `TRUE` for `WM_ERASEBKGND`, and `InvalidateRect` for `WM_SIZE` and `WM_MOVE` ). I have found nothing on the internet to help me.

**Question**: How to change my code to fix the error I face?

Comment: Why do you draw the dialog in WM_CTLCOLORDLG instead of WM_PAINT?

Comment: Does the map have any functional purpose at all? Will you draw additional things on it? If not I would advise against spending time on irrelevant stuff, and for removing the image and the background pattern altogether.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I am a beginner and had no idea how to properly implement it.

Comment: @Dialecticus: My clients force this type of background-in my opinion it is just an " unnecessary bling ", but what can I do...

Comment: Just looking at the wrong image, I suspect there's a bug in how you send the coordinates for the gradient fill.  I could imagine that if you got the coordinates in the wrong order or miscounted, you could end up with a couple triangles of color like you see there.  I would focus there and watch what happens in the debugger.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: I came to the same conclusion before but couldn't find a flaw in my math. It seems that member *rodrigo* succeeded in it. Thank you for your comment. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are abusing the `WM_CTLCOLORDLG` message. It is intended to provide an easy way to change the background color of the dialog, not to custom paint it.

You should just return `NULL_BRUSH` there, or even ignore the message altogether, and do your background painting in `WM_ERASEBKGND`.

Or maybe even better, you can ignore `WM_ERASEBKGND` and do your painting in `WM_PAINT`, just as any other window.

**UPDATE**: After a few comments below the problem seems to be the order of the vertices in the call to `GradientFill()` triangles. That is:

- The vertices are listed clockwise: the triangle is drawn.
- The vertices are listed counter-clockwise: the triangle is not drawn.

Or maybe is the other way around, I never can tell...

Anyway, there is still the mystery of why sometimes it works no matter the order and why sometimes it only works with a specific order. And moreover, is this documented anywhere?

I'm guessing that it may be a driver/2D-acceleration issue... so it will depend on whether the DC is on display or on memory, but it is difficult to say.

Comment: I did try that but failed. I will try again and report my results. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: OK, after changing the `case WM_CTLCOLORDIALOG` into `case WM_ERASEBKGND`, and after changing the `return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);` into `return TRUE`, I get the same effect. I have tried to return `TRUE` from `WM_ERASEBKGND` and to paint the picture in `WM_PAINT`. The `HDC` was obtained from call to `BeginPaint`, the painting code is the same except that `(HDC)wParam` was substituted with the DC from `BeginPaint`-the remains. Any thoughts? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: A wild guess: the EMF is changing something in the DC that makes your triangles not working. Try calling `SaveDC()` before `PlayEnhMetaFile()` and `RestoreDC()` after. Also, check the return value of `GradientFill` for errors.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: Ops! Forgot to ping you in the previous comment!

Comment: I have commented out the part that draws `EMF` but problem persists. I have commented out the drawing of the footer and painted that rectangle with stock brush ( `LTGRAY_BRUSH` ). The problem **seems to disappear**. My function `drawFooter` calls `GradientFill` API, described as above. Maybe I am passing incorrect values for vertexes? I will try to experiment with that.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: Now I'm guessing about the _winding order_ of the triangles. Try changing the order of `Vertex{1,2,3}` from `0, 1, 2` into `0, 2, 1`.

Comment: You are right, I have switched the indexes and it works! Please edit your answer with **detailed explanation** why this switch works **so I can learn from my mistake.** You will get +1 from me, and I will accept your answer. Thank you so much! Best regards.

Comment: Thank you-I guess your explanation will have to suffice for now. That was one **elusive** bug to catch! Thank you so much again, I can not upvote your answer enough. Further more, the bug does not reproduce on `Windows 7`, but I work on `Windows XP` so you might be right-it could be the driver issue. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You're handling the wrong message.

You shouldn't paint anything on `WM_CTLCOLORDLG` message. Just move your painting code to `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler.

Comment: I will try that and report my results. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: OK, after changing the `case WM_CTLCOLORDIALOG` into `case WM_ERASEBKGND`, and after changing the `return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);` into `return TRUE`, I get the same effect. All the other code remained the same. Any thoughts? Thanks anyway. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Your next problem is you're repainting the complete window. Note that the left portion of your window, that *did* needed updating, is painted OK. And the problem is the main (right) portion of the window, that did not actually needed to be updated after moving the window from the left.

While inside the `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler, you can call `GetUpdateRect()` to get the rectangle that needs updating.

If you don't want to change your code too much, you can at least call e.g. `IntersectClipRect()` API before drawing anything. This will clip all your painting to that rectangle.

Comment: I will look `MSDN` documentation for those and see what I can do. Meanwhile, this could be important: I have commented out the drawing of the footer and painted that rectangle with stock brush ( `LTGRAY_BRUSH` ). The problem **seems to disappear**. My function `drawFooter` calls `GradientFill` API, described as above. Maybe I am passing incorrect values for vertexes? I will try to experiment with that.